# How do I disable Windows + K shortcut key on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

I don't want to disable any other shortcuts... just that one. I have muscle memory attached to it for using it with another app and I don't want to see the Devices charm ever again!

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one way to archive this.

### You can disable all the Windows + X hotkeys in gpedit.msc

1. type gpedit.msc on your start screen
2. The newly opened window go to:
    User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / File Explorer 
   then select **Turn off Windows+X hotkeys** there select *Enabled* and restart your computer.

### You can disable only the Windows + K hotkey via key remapping program

There are outside a lot of key remapping program which could help you to do what you want. E.g. [KeyTweak](http://windows.appstorm.net/how-to/hardware/how-to-remap-your-keyboard-with-keytweak/) or [Sharp Keys](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/01/02/remap-keyboard/).   **The most rich feature set is available in** [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which enable to write scripts, simple or complex. (You need to write a script to remap a key). I suggest it for you, you need to give a look at the documentation of [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

You can disable a key by returning it immediately, for the Win+K the script will look like this:

```
#k::
#K::
return
```

This will disable both Win+k and Win+K hot key. ( # is stand for Win key.)
**Reboot needed to get changes work!**

**Edit:** After the remapping you don't need to run the remapping program, it write the changes to the registry. So you can even delete the program after you set the remapping and restart your PC.

### You can disable only the Windows + K hotkey via the registry

If you want to know whats going on your system, you could do the remmapping manualy in the registry. [Here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8359-problem-remapping-key-in-cygwin-and-putty/#entry52760) is a good forum post about it.

Comment: I don't want to completely disable the Win+K scan code because I want to use that key combination with another app, instead of the default. The AutoHotKey thing looks interesting... but complicated.