# Disabling the Win+C hotkey for the Charms Bar in Win 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, shortcuts, hotkeys, charms-bar

I am trying to turn off the hotkey for the Charms Bar (Win+C) in Windows 8. Is there a registry entry to do this or some other way? I want to be able to use that hotkey for something else.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Niels

Comment: Similar but not quite the same. I would prefer being able to actually turn off the charms bar... The other way requires a pretty high level of understanding for AutoHotkey.

Comment: Also see [How can I disable the Windows 8 charms bar?](http://superuser.com/questions/399029/how-can-i-disable-the-windows-8-charms-bar)

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to disable all win hotkeys (or even win key all together):

Using group policy (gpedit.msc) or using registry editor (regedit). 
You can find more information on how to do it, [here](http://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-all-win-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-in-windows/).

There's also another super user post on this, which you can find [here](https://superuser.com/questions/670731/how-do-i-disable-windows-k-shortcut-key-on-windows-8)